# How to parse a loosely structured document

Tags: python, text-analysis

I am analyzing data feeds which have data somewhat like this

```
RAM 4 GB DDR3
RAM 16GB DIMM
memory 4GB DDR3 MHz         // no value for MHz 
memory 4GB DDR3 1333 MHz    // no the order of MHz is not fixed
ram 6GB, 1333 MHz, DDR3     // comma used as delimiter

Processor Intel Core i7-3612QM
Processor Intel Core i7 2630QM
processor i3-380,2.53 GHz          //380 used for model number instead of 380M and model number separated by '-' and clock speed separated by ','
Processor Core i3-380 2.53 GHz 
Processor Intel Ci3 - 2330 (2nd Gen), 2.53 GHz   // multiple symbols used as delimiters(',','-')

Hard drive 500GB 5400RPM
Hard Disk Drive 1.5 TB
Hard Disk 256 GB
```

now i need to analyze what each specification means like in `ram 6GB, 1333 MHz, DDR3` i need to figure out that 6GB is the capacity, 1333 MHz is the frequency and DDR3 is the type of ram. But the problem as you can see is these are very irregular(some entries have some fields and dont have others and sometimes whitespaces are used as separators ,sometimes `,`s and sometimes `-`s). My first reaction was using regex but i soon realised that it was stupid. Then i thought that i can `split` on the separator(`,` in the above case) but even the separator is not fixed. Also this approach would be useless for entries like this `memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3` Using whitespace as separator for this entry would make it look like `4`  `GB`  `1333`  `MHz`  are different but actually `4 GB` and `1333 MHz` are different.
Also how can i programatically decide that `Intel Core i3`, `Core i3`, `i3-380` and `Ci3` imply Intel Core i3? I understand that i have to tell the library once that `Intel Core i3`, `Core i3` and `Ci3` mean the same thing. But later when analysis the text it should be able to figure out.
The above mentioned lists of entries show how variable can the entries be. Is there some python library(or in any other language) that can help me in dealing with these tasks?

Comment: Google `python regex` and follow some tutorials. Regular expressions will be your best friend when parsing data that has a simple structure like this.

Comment: What kind of output do you want? A dictionary? Or is the structure fixed (i.e. they will always be either hard drives, RAM, or processors)?

Comment: @minitech for each entry i would require a tokenised dictionary with key as specification type and value as specification value like for `6 GB` or `6GB` i would need key as capacity and value as 6 GB. I can figure out what type of entry it is like ram or hard disk or processor

Comment: @lovesh: Sounds exactly like a regex with named groups: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict

Comment: @Blender Can you please provide a samle regex that can gives the processor details by analysing the processor entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to build a set of classes that directly correspond to each type of entry, then that's probably the way to go. For example, a class for RAM might be:

```
class Memory:
    def __init__(self, s):
        if not 'RAM' in s and not 'memory' in s:
            raise ValueError("Not a string that describes RAM.")

        self.capacity = int(re.match(r'(\d+) ?GB', s)[1])
```

Then just try each class until one fits.

Comment: I dont have to just extract the capacity(6 GB) from a RAM entry but i need to figure out if there is more like type(DDR2 or DDR3) or if there is frequency mentioned like(1333 MHz) and they might not always be in the same order

Comment: @lovesh: That was just an example. One regular expression for each.

Comment: So if i am looking for say 3 types(capacity,frequency,type) of information in each entry, i should be running 3 regex against each entry

Comment: @minitech: Well no you can match multiple groups in a single regex.

Comment: @jdi: lovesh says they can be in any order. It might be possible (lookaheads confuse me, sorry) but it won't be simpler, that's for sure...

Comment: Oh...any order, nevermind :-) But if they can at least be in the same order but optional fields..something like:  `re.search(r'(?:RAM|memory) ?(?P<size>\d+ ?[a-z]+) ?(?P<freq>\d+ +[a-z]+)? ?(?P<type>[a-z]+\d*)?', l, re.I).groupdict()`

Comment: But they are not in the same order like `memory 4GB DDR3 1333 MHz` and `memory 4GB DDR3 MHz`. And you see there is no value for `MHz` in second entry so a regular expression like `\d+ ?MHz` would mistakenly give me `3 MHz` which is not correct. So i basically i need something which understands what is and what is not acceptable for  `MHz`

Comment: @lovesh: My snippet will parse that line though.

Comment: @lovesh: You can fix getting an extra 3 by using word boundaries: `\b\d+ ?MHz` (Also, why is that even in there? "DDR3 MHz" is just silly.)

Comment: @lovesh: The point is that there are enough regex tools available to do this, whether you parse a line multiple times, or once. You just define the patterns and pull out the info. Its all a matter of reviewing how to use regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

First off, are you sure there's no other systematic way to get the device info? Most system utilities provide a standardized way to export information.

If you absolutely must parse this structure, you will have to use `regex` or **Regular Expressions** for dealing with such kind of loosely structured documents.

Although this document in general doesn't have a uniform structure, each line in this document **does** have it's own standardized structure.

Logic:

1) Parse the file one line at a time.
2) Read the first token and use the approach for parsing the remainder of that line.

For eg: If you encounter the token "RAM", you know that it's always followed by a numeric size, unit and then the type.

Happy Coding!